# Token balancing in a blank new Cassandra-Cluster

Tags: docker, cassandra, token

My setup consists of 3 Cassandra nodes. every node runs as part of a docker container.

One seednode and two normal nodes.

I use cassandra:latest which mean at this time version 3.11.4.

All nodes run in one cluster.

All nodes run in one datacenter.

I use the the following setup in my docker-compose.yml

```
- "CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch"
- "CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS=8"
- "MAX_HEAP_SIZE=512M"
- "HEAP_NEWSIZE=128M"
```

Heap-size are so small because it tests only the start of the cluster and my notebook has not enough ram.
The partitioner is the default `Murmur3Partitioner` of cassandra.

I start only the cluster, no keyspace-creation or other things a going through the thing.

In every documentation that i found there is the statement of the balanced token-range and unbalanced token distribution is bad etc. etc.

But what ist a balanced token-range?

When I start the cluster, first the seedcontainer, with an intervall of 1 minute each other node comes up and ready.

The cluster is healthy and there are no errors in log. As the result of `docker-compose ps` describes:

```
         Name                        Command               State                                Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker_cassandra-seed_1   docker-entrypoint.sh bash  ...   Up      7000/tcp, 7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 0.0.0.0:23232->9042/tcp, 9160/tcp
docker_cassandra1_1       docker-entrypoint.sh bash  ...   Up      7000/tcp, 7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp
docker_cassandra2_1       docker-entrypoint.sh bash  ...   Up      7000/tcp, 7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp
```

If the cluster is up, there are 3 nodes with 8 vnodes runs on each node.
It is a cluster distribution of 24 with always 24 token ranges.

The token range in Cassandra is -2^63 till +2^63 - 1 (java long).
If I call a

`docker exec -ti docker_cassandra-seed_1 nodetool ring`

i receive the following result.

```
docker exec -ti docker_cassandra-seed_1 nodetool ring

Datacenter: tc1
==========
Address     Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token

172.27.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  254.57 KiB      88.87%              -8870864291163548206
172.27.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  231.07 KiB      55.89%              -8804151848356105327
172.27.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  220.44 KiB      55.24%              -8578084366820530367
172.27.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  231.07 KiB      55.89%              -7746741366682664202
172.27.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  231.07 KiB      55.89%              -7013522326538302096
172.27.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  254.57 KiB      88.87%              -6994428155886831685
172.27.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  220.44 KiB      55.24%              -6650863707982675450
172.27.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  231.07 KiB      55.89%              -5995004048488281144
172.27.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  231.07 KiB      55.89%              -5683587085031530885
172.27.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  231.07 KiB      55.89%              -5274940575732780430
172.27.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  254.57 KiB      88.87%              -5184169415607375486
172.27.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  220.44 KiB      55.24%              -2082614198258325552
172.27.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  254.57 KiB      88.87%              -1084866128895283137
172.27.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  220.44 KiB      55.24%              2495470503021543046
172.27.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  254.57 KiB      88.87%              3043280549254813456
172.27.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  231.07 KiB      55.89%              3058642754102082410
172.27.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  220.44 KiB      55.24%              3117172086630093502
172.27.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  254.57 KiB      88.87%              3405798334726690865
172.27.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  220.44 KiB      55.24%              3829479365384141235
172.27.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  220.44 KiB      55.24%              4124513942316551627
172.27.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  220.44 KiB      55.24%              4807293191442647176
172.27.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  231.07 KiB      55.89%              4911525338969505185
172.27.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  254.57 KiB      88.87%              8068956543491535994
172.27.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  254.57 KiB      88.87%              8197176123795617738
```

Which means the difference between every token range in the ring is totally different.

Or in other words, the perfect case for the calculation where `((2^63 * 2) - 1) / (3 * 8) = 768.614.336.404.564.000` tokens per node in an ideal token distribution.

Sorry I have only excel at the fast here for calculating (round the 10000s):

```
-9.223.372.036.854.770.000  Long Min
-8.870.864.291.163.540.000  352.507.745.691.229.000
-8.804.151.848.356.100.000  66.712.442.807.440.400
-8.578.084.366.820.530.000  226.067.481.535.570.000
-7.746.741.366.682.660.000  831.343.000.137.870.000
-7.013.522.326.538.300.000  733.219.040.144.359.000
-6.994.428.155.886.830.000  19.094.170.651.470.800
-6.650.863.707.982.670.000  343.564.447.904.160.000
-5.995.004.048.488.280.000  655.859.659.494.390.000
-5.683.587.085.031.530.000  311.416.963.456.750.000
-5.274.940.575.732.780.000  408.646.509.298.750.000
-5.184.169.415.607.370.000  90.771.160.125.410.300
-2.082.614.198.258.320.000  3.101.555.217.349.050.000
-1.084.866.128.895.280.000  997.748.069.363.040.000
2.495.470.503.021.540.000   3.580.336.631.916.820.000
3.043.280.549.254.810.000   547.810.046.233.270.000
3.058.642.754.102.080.000   15.362.204.847.269.900
3.117.172.086.630.090.000   58.529.332.528.010.200
3.405.798.334.726.690.000   288.626.248.096.600.000
3.829.479.365.384.140.000   423.681.030.657.450.000
4.124.513.942.316.550.000   295.034.576.932.410.000
4.807.293.191.442.640.000   682.779.249.126.090.000
4.911.525.338.969.500.000   104.232.147.526.860.000
8.068.956.543.491.530.000   3.157.431.204.522.030.000
8.197.176.123.795.610.000   128.219.580.304.080.000
9.223.372.036.854.770.000   Long Max
```

The right column describes the distribution of each token range. And here is a big gap between the biggest and the smallest token range.

Or a little bit consolidated (from the middle of the result) that is totally uneven or unbalanced or undistributed:

```
-5184169415607375486
-2082614198258325552
-1084866128895283137
```

After some tesing, i´ve setup a super simple thing.
One pc (with ubuntu 18.04, java 1.8.0_201, cassandra version 3.6).
Install, let all the parameters to default, drive the cassandra service up and look at the token-distribution.

Here is the result:
[tokendistribution on a new cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcoV5.png)

So my question is: What means balanced token-range in a Cassandra cluster?

Comment: Have you defined num_tokens in cassandra.yaml?

Comment: Yes, set num_tokens to 8.
But i makes no difference if i set num_tokens to 1 or 256. In any case there is an big unbalance in the token ranges.

Comment: What i mean in my comment above: There is in any case a unbalancing of the tokens, no matter what the number in num_token is. The difference is even the number of unbalanced tokenranges of the vnodes.

Comment: can use `allocate_tokens_keyspace` when bringing up a node. The node's tokens are then allocated to optimize the load distribution for the replication strategy of that keyspace.

Comment: https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/02/21/set-up-a-cluster-with-even-token-distribution.html

Comment: Thank you @ChrisLohfink for the article. But, if the balancing of token is so important, why this parameter ist per default not activated?
I will try this in my testcluster and inform here about the result!
Thanks again...

Comment: C* doesnt know the replication your going to use and it differs based on the cluster so it cant optimally do it without that additional knowledge. Admittedly it could probably assume 3 per DC since thats what most people use but ultimately came down to the person who implemented it didnt feel comfortable enough with that assumption.

Answer (score 2):

As described in this link 
https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/02/21/set-up-a-cluster-with-even-token-distribution.html
it seems to be the solution, at least for the distribution of tokens and data for a keyspace.
The following steps i take to get a balanced system:

1. Setup cassandra.yaml for the seed-node with (for my testcase num_tokens=8) let the other parameter as default
2. startup the seednode, wait until ready
3. connect via cqlsh or programmatic solution and create the keyspace (for my test-case with replication-factor=1).
4. shutdown the seed-node
5. edit the cassandra.yaml of the seed-node and outcomment/add the parameter for `allocate_tokens_for_keyspace: [your_keyspace_name_from_step_3]`
6. startup the seed-node and wait until the node is ready
7. edit the cassandra.yaml for the second node in the cluster take the step 5. in this file and the num_token equal to num_token of the seed-node.
8. run the second node an wait until it is ready
9. do the steps 7-8 for any other node in your cluster.

With that and e.g. a testrun with adding 2.000.000 datarows in a testtable in the keyspace i see the following result:

```
docker exec -ti docker_cassandra-seed_1 nodetool status
Datacenter: tc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.30.10.4  36.03 MiB  8            33.3%             1e0d781f-d71f-4704-bcd1-efb5d4caff0e  rack1
UN  172.30.10.2  36.75 MiB  8            33.3%             56287b3c-b0f1-489f-930e-c7b00df896f3  rack1
UN  172.30.10.3  36.03 MiB  8            33.3%             943acc5f-7257-414a-b36c-c06dcb53e67d  rack1
```

Even the tokendistribution ist better then before:

```
172.30.10.2                         6.148.914.691.236.510.000
172.30.10.3                         6.148.914.691.236.520.000
172.30.10.4                         5.981.980.531.853.070.000
```

At the moment, there is some clarification about the problem with the uneven distribution, so thank you again Chris Lohfink for the link with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve testing a little bit around the above scenario.
My testcluster consists of 5 nodes (1 seed, 4 normal nodes).

The first 5 steps from above remains valid:

1. Setup cassandra.yaml for the seed-node with (for my testcase
   num_tokens=8) let the other parameter as default
2. startup the seednode, wait until ready
3. connect via cqlsh or programmatic
   solution and create the keyspace (for my test-case with
   replication-factor=1).
4. shutdown the seed-node, edit the cassandra.yaml of the seed-node and outcomment/add the parameter for `allocate_tokens_for_keyspace: [your_keyspace_name_from_step_3]`
5. startup the seed-node and wait until the node is ready

Then, you can startup all the other nodes (in my case 4) at same time (or with 1 minute delay between startup of each node), but automated. Important is, that all nodes have the `allocate_tokens_for_keyspace: [your_keyspace....]` set.

After all nodes are up, and fill with 1.000.000 rows, there´s an even balance of 20%.

That scenario makes the life easier, if you start a cluster with a lot of nodes.